# Regex: Few Matches with * Quantifier

Tags: c#, .net, regex

My regex is ending by quantifier * . 
But I have few matches in a string. How can I make so it still found all matches ? My regex:

```
((CMD1|CMD2)+(?::|;)+.*)
```

And the test string is `"cmd1: test. test. test cmd2: test2. test2. test2"`
So I need to get matches:

```
cmd1: test. test. test
cmd2: test2. test2. test2
```

Commands could be random words like "Look", "Take", "Go". There could be n-occurance of any commands in one string.
Example:

```
Go: some sentences. and more. Take: other more sentences, and even more text here. Look: more and more. and more.
```

Comment: I think you may use `Regex.Split(s, @"(?!^)\s*(?=CMD\d+[:;])", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)`. If your `CMD` is a placeholder, use the alternation for the command names, `(?=CMD\d+[:;])` => `(?=(?:CMD1|CMD2|CMDn)[:;])`. If commands are always separated with whitespace, replace `(?!^)\s*` with `\s+`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a positive lookahead:

[\w+:.*?(?= \w+:|$)](https://regex101.com/r/V3Phhj/2)

- Match a word character one or more times `\w+`
- Match a colon `:`
- Match any character zero or more times `.*`
- Make it non greedy `?`
- A positive lookahead which asserts a word character one or more times `\w+` followed by a colon `:` or `|` the end of the sting `(?= \w+:|$)`

[Demo](http://rextester.com/DCOZI44708)

Comment: Thanks. That is what I was looking for. For my case I modified regex: (Go|Take|Look):.*?(?= \w+:|$)

Answer (score 1):

```
string s = "Go: some sentences. and more. Take: other more sentences, and even more text here. Look: more and more. and more.";
var matches = Regex.Matches(s, @"(?i)(go|take|look):.+?(?=\s+\w+:)");
```

You can remove `\s+`, but in this case you should call `Trim` on result string.

Comment: there could be n-matches of commands, and commands could be different.

Answer (score 1):

A general rule when writing regex is that when you want to find all occurrences of a pattern and put each pattern into its own match, you write a regex for *that pattern*, not *that pattern quantified `*` times*. Otherwise, you will end up putting the whole string into one single match.

I edited the regex for you:

```
CMD(?:1|2)(?::|;).*?(?=$|CMD)
```

The beginning is pretty much self-explanatory. Towards the end, I matched `.` with a lazy quantifier `*?`. This will stop matching as soon as the string after it matches the lookahead. The lookahead just matches another `CMD` or the end of the string.

Remember to turn on case insensitive option!

Comment: it gives only the first match. I can do that: remove match from the string until the string does not have any matches. But thats a workaround.

Comment: @DmytroSh. Use `Regex.Matches` instead of `Regex.Match`. The former returns a `MatchCollection`.